# Fix the width for inner div same as outer div

Tags: html, css

this is my html (for example)

```
<div id="wrap">
    Some relative item placed item
    <div id="fixed">hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
</div>
```

here is my css:

```
#wrap{ 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%; 
    background:#ccc; 
}
#fixed{ 
    width:inherit;
}
```

I want to make the second div that is 'fixed' to have same width as the first 'wrap'. I tried a lot, but i can't do it.
Is it possible to do this without any javascript?

Any suggestion..please.

here is the fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sris/tktdf1kk/

Comment: Instead of `width:inherit;` use `word-wrap: break-word;`. Updated jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tktdf1kk/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave your width alone.  Divs already expand 100% of their containing div.  The reason your text is not wrapping is because it's all one word.  Add the CSS:

```
#fixed {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you James for this awesome simple solution.

Comment: @user3784251 Not a problem.  I'm glad I could help.  Don't forget to mark this as the answer when you are able.  :)